# Clickable bootstrap row with angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have got a table, styled with bootstrap. The content of this table is filled using Angular.js. How do I make a row clickable so it will call a function in the scope?

The following code does not work for me (the ng-click part):

Table:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="ingredient in ingredients" ng-click="setSelected({{$index}});">
                <td>{{ ingredient.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ingredient.status }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.setSelected = function(index) {
    $scope.selected = $scope.ingredients[index];
    console.log($scope.selected);
};
```

Comment: I think you just need to remove the {{}} around $index but you should describe better how it fails.  For example you show that you're logging it but not the output of the log.

Comment: Nothing happens, no logging. But the {{$index}} is rendered to an numeric value.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Suggestion and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnvSD/1/):

```
<tr ng-repeat="ingredient in ingredients" ng-click="setSelected();">
    <td>{{ ingredient.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ ingredient.status }}</td>
</tr>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.ingredients = [
        {'name': 'potato'},
        {'name': 'tomato'}
    ];

    $scope.setSelected = function() {
        $scope.selected = this.ingredient;
        console.log($scope.selected);
    };

}
</script>
```

Comment: To decouple controller and template you can use `ng-click="setSelected(ingredient);"` and `$scope.setSelected = function(item) { ... };`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just pass the ingredient in argument

ng-click="setSelected(ingredient)"

and in controller

```
   $scope.setSelected = function(my_ingredient) {
       $scope.selected = my_ingredient;
       console.log($scope.selected);
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<table class="table-hover">
```

CSS:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

And if also whats made the tr selectable:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-click="doSomething()">
```

CSS:

```
tr[ng-click] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[View JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pdorgambide/vb7tmLp4/)

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 6**

HTML:

```
<tr (click)="doSomething()">
```

CSS:

```
tr:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```