# ng-click on <tr> doing nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have consulted these related articles, but the presented solutions do not work:

- [Clickable bootstrap row with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658454/clickable-bootstrap-row-with-angular)
- [Adding parameter to ng-click function inside ng-repeat doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-seems-not-to-work)
- [Angular ng-click not working in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512016/angular-ng-click-not-working-in-div)

Here is my plunkr:: http://plnkr.co/edit/kha6mAKDBtrY0XtTc6Wp?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table>
  <caption>Troubles with ng-repeat and ng-click</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Occupation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-click="alert('hi')">
      <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.occupation}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
var app = angular.module("plunker", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.employees = [
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      occupation: "Miner"
    },
    {
      name: "Theressa",
      occupation: "Construction Worker"
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: `ng-click` isn't like inline js. InlineJS is awful. You need to do `$scope.alert = alert.bind(window)` in order for it to be available in your view. However, you should also not directly access globals like that. It would be ideal to inject `$window` into the controller and do `$scope.alert = $window.alert.bind($window);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, but `alert` is not part of your `$scope` so it won't do anything.

You can add it in your controller:

```
$scope.alert = function(message) { alert(message); }
```

Comment: even though alert is a global function ?

Comment: How would you call an object function?  ``ng-click="myObject.method(params)``?  It currently does nothing?

Comment: Yes, what you access in the HTML are all the properties of the `$scope` object.

Comment: `ng-click="myObject.method(params)` will work if `$scope.myObject` exists and has a `method` function